# SQL Update the Indicator Column Based on Change of LOB Column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a table with columns LOB, Report Date, and Indicator.

```
    LOB     |      Report Date | Indicator 
-------------------+------------------------------
 CNS        |2022-07-20        | 0
 MNR        |2022-07-11        | 0
 MNR        |2022-07-10        | 0
 MNR        |2022-07-04        | 0
 CNS        |2022-07-01        | 0
 CNS        |2022-01-26        | 0
 MNR        |2022-01-03        | 0
 MNR        |2022-01-03        | 0
 BBP        |2021-12-29        | 0
 BBP        |2021-12-22        | 0
 BBP        |2021-12-21        | 0
 BBP        |2021-12-16        | 0
 MNR        |2021-11-11        | 0
 MNR        |2021-11-06        | 0
 MNR        |2021-11-02        | 0
```

```
OUTPUT:
    LOB     |      Report Date | Indicator 
-------------------+------------------------------
 CNS        |2022-07-20        | 1
 MNR        |2022-07-11        | 0
 MNR        |2022-07-10        | 0
 MNR        |2022-07-04        | 1
 CNS        |2022-07-01        | 0
 CNS        |2022-01-26        | 1
 MNR        |2022-01-03        | 0
 MNR        |2022-01-03        | 1
 BBP        |2021-12-29        | 0
 BBP        |2021-12-22        | 0
 BBP        |2021-12-21        | 0
 BBP        |2021-12-16        | 1
 MNR        |2021-11-11        | 0
 MNR        |2021-11-06        | 0
 MNR        |2021-11-02        | 0
```

Need to Update the indicator column based on LOB change. When ever the LOB change is happened then I need to update the Indictor column value to “1” or else the default Indicator column value is “0”

For example, in the bottom of the table the LOB starts with "MNR" then later the LOB changed to "BBP" here I need to Update as "1" ... In the same way from "BBP" it got changed to "MNR" here I need to update as "1" ... When ever the change of LOB happened I need to update the Indicator as "1"

Kindly help me with the Solution.

Comment: What have you tried so far, please share your current attempt; why have you tagged two different versions of SQL Server? You should TAG the version you are using or the minimum required compatability.

Comment: I don't understand the logic: what column are you ordering by?

Comment: Is having the indicator flag as a column of the table a hard requirement? Or would a view adding 'inidicator' also work for you?  
Depending on the use case, you could simply make a copy of the table and compare the updated table with the original copy, or make the table temporal and compute 'indicator' from the history.

Comment: I don't have two tables, I have only one table. The OUTPUT result set I kept only for to understand the scenario. [The OUTPUT result set which I displayed in my question is my requirement ]

Comment: What constitutes a LOB change? Does CNS change to MNR, for example? If so, how do you identify it as a changed value as opposed to a pre-existing value, especially if this is all in one table?

Comment: What determins the "when" part - is it `report date`? Showing your data in the correct order and explaining the actual logic would help.

Comment: The report date columns indicates the date where the LOB got changed. From Source on daily basics we use to get LOB and Report Date values in text file. Post loading the data from that Text file, then I need to update the Indicator columns from my side. Based on the change I need to update as "1" or else it should be "0"

Comment: Did change to Tag and question/data

Comment: So issue `UPDATE` statements? Your data does not have enough details to determine what to set to what. For example, why are both `CNS / 2022-07-20` and `CNS / 2022-01-26` in your output set to `1`, but not `CNS / 2022-07-01`? If this is because your input table contains this data somehow, post that as well.

Comment: Note also that there is no way for the database to distinguish between two rows with identical column values (like `MNR / 2022-01-03`) unless another column is available to break ties.

Comment: It can be any LOB... If an LOB got changed on particular day then I need to Update the indicator as "1".... For example, in the bottom of the table the LOB starts with "MNR" then later the LOB changed to "BBP" here I need to Update as "1" ... In the same way from "BBP" it got changed to "MNR" here I need to update as "1" ... When ever the change of LOB happened I need to update the Indicator as "1"

Comment: Why don't you just update the indicator along with the LOB, then, however the LOB is getting updated? In fact, I'd go so far as to say that's the *only* way of doing it, because you cannot set these values correctly just from your input and output alone -- I invite you to try it. The process that takes care of these updates should also set the indicator.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this should work.

```
WITH cte as (
select LOB,
       Report_date,
       CASE
         WHEN  LOB <> lead(LOB) OVER (order by Report_date DESC) 
         THEN 1
         ELSE 0
       END as Indicator
from  tableA
)
UPDATE tableA set tableA.Indicator = cte.Indicator
FROM cte
WHERE tableA.LOB = cte.LOB and tableA.Report_date = cte.Report_date
```

[db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=c1cfd9e9edfa1c58820101991dc282e2)

And as @stu mentioned. you could just directly update the cte

```
WITH cte as (
select LOB,
       Report_date, Indicator,
       CASE
         WHEN  LOB <> lead(LOB) OVER (order by Report_date DESC) 
         THEN 1
         ELSE 0
       END as NewIndicator
from  tableA
)
UPDATE cte set Indicator = NewIndicator
```

Comment: Why not just update the CTE [directly](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=4dec932b9c506ca11a62478498915af2)?

Comment: yep, your right. I didn't realize you could do that

Comment: A cte or derived table is updatable provided it selects from a single base table.